# What is difference between if(!boolVariable) vs if (boolVariable == false) in .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In my project, code is

```
if (boolVariable == false)
```

So what if I use,

```
if(!boolVariable)
```

Is there any difference or both are same?

Comment: Why is there an `of` in your second sample?

Comment: Why are you asking us about performance differences when you can simply test it for yourself?

Comment: @PhilippGrathwohl it is just to convey the thought. it is not syntax.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I dont know how to test. so I asked, if you know the difference, let me know

Comment: You do know how to test.  You just didn't bother to do it.  What is performance?  It's speed of execution, right?  So, you execute both and time them to see which, if either, is faster.  That's just common sense; nothing specific to programming.  Obviously those lines will execute so quickly that you won't be able to effectively time just one, which is why such tests involve executing the relevant code in a loop that executes a large enough number of times that differences in execution speed can be discerned from noise.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank You

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: The only reason you would ever use the first would be if it was a Nullable bool, not just a simple bool.

Answer (score 2):

Writing `== false` and `== true` is redundant. There is no performance difference. It can be taken to arbitrary extremes, too. If you start writing

```
if (condition == false) { ... }
```

Then why not

```
if ((condition == false) == true) { ... }
```

Or why not

```
if ((someExp == anotherExp) == true) { ... }
```

Hence, `if` condition is a `boolean` expression, then you don't need to add `== false;` that's what operator ! is for ;)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: Both variants are compiled to identical [IL code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language):

```
Private Sub TestEqualsFalse(value As Boolean)
    If value = False Then
        Beep()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TestNotValue(value As Boolean)
    If Not value Then
        Beep()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the generated IL:

```
.method private static 
    void TestEqualsFalse (
        bool 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x21d4
    // Code size 18 (0x12)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] bool
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0003: ceq
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: brfalse.s IL_0010

    IL_0009: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction::Beep()
    IL_000e: nop
    IL_000f: nop

    IL_0010: nop
    IL_0011: ret
} // end of method Module1::TestEqualsFalse

.method private static 
    void TestNotValue (
        bool 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x21f4
    // Code size 18 (0x12)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] bool
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0003: ceq
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: brfalse.s IL_0010

    IL_0009: call void [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction::Beep()
    IL_000e: nop
    IL_000f: nop

    IL_0010: nop
    IL_0011: ret
} // end of method Module1::TestNotValue
```

I used [ILSpy](https://ilspy.net/) to view the IL code.